# excel workday and if function not giving correct days

Tags: excel-formula

I have an Excel if formula with workday calculation, below gives me 108566 days I'm expecting 2 days. [@[Notification Date]] is 03/11/2023 and [@[Execution date]] is 07/11/2023. Can someone please help?

```
=IF([@[Notification Date]]="", "TBD",WORKDAY([@[Notification Date]],[@[Execution date]]))
```

Comment: I suppose you are looking for `NETWORKDAYS`. Read documentation of both to decide.

Comment: Please see [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) and read [How much research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592) and don't forget to read [Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236) . Also check out the
[tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour), and [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)

Comment: The numerical representation of 7/11/2023 in excel is 45118, so what you are actually getting out of the `WORKDAY` function is 45118 workdays past 3/11/2023. It's not clear from your question why you would expect the result to be 2 if the dates are 4 months apart, though.

Comment: @KeyubW the format of dates is dependent on system language, therefore Excel could also default dates to DMY format rather than MDY. In that case the dates are 3rd and 7th of November.

Comment: @P.b Right, thanks for clearing that up. I've never liked MDY personally, but it's a rather engrained habit.